# CocoaPods failing to install from GitHub with "No such file or directory" error

Tags: git, cocoapods, osx-yosemite

I've created a Podfile with two libraries. The first, an existing pod, installs perfectly. The second, which points to a GitHub project, fails with a `Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory` error.

Running `pod install --verbose` I can see that the files are being cloned from GitHub and stored in a folder called something like `/var/folders/s8/05t8tk155t9dd6kzm9tlfpq00000gn/T/d20150526-5339-15aks97` successfully but then the folder is immediately deleted before the command to copy those files from that temp folder to the `Pods` folder within the project. Which is why the command fails with `No such file or directory`.

Based on other answers on the site I've cleared my `~/.cocoapods` folder and run `pod setup` over again. I've run `sudo gem update` which completed successfully. I've also copied and pasted the `git clone` command that `pod install --verbose` says it is running and it completes without any errors.

I just don't know why that folder in `/var/folder` is being deleted before the copy and I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

The repository is cloned in a temporary folder, and then only the files recognised as sources are added to your project, can you post your Podfile?

Comment: I meant that it's normal that the temporary folder will be deleted immediately after the need operation to extract files. Did you have success then?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Updating cocoapods solved it.

```
sudo gem update cocoapods
```